# How can I get these equations to align in \align?

Tags: align, alignment

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
&[f_2,\phi](a)=0, &&[f_2,\psi](a)=0, &[f_2,\phi](b)=-\beta_2, &&[f_2,\psi](b)=\beta_1.\\
&[f_1,\phi](a)=-\alpha_2, &&[f_1,\psi](a)=\alpha_1, &[f_1,\phi](b)=0, &&[f_1,\psi](b)=0.
\end{align*}
```

which produces the following

[image]

which isnt aligned after the second column. I'd like the alignment to coincide with each ' [ ' .  Any ideas on how to line these up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use  an `&` between each equation, and an `&` at the aligment point (=) in each equation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
[f_2,\phi](a)&=0, &[f_2,\psi](a)&=0, &[f_2,\phi](b)&=-\beta_2, &[f_2,\psi](b)&=\beta_1.\\
[f_1,\phi](a)&=-\alpha_2, &[f_1,\psi](a)&=\alpha_1, &[f_1,\phi](b)&=0, &[f_1,\psi](b)&=0.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If you want the aligment at `[` not `=` that would be less conventional, but keep the `&` between the equations but move the aligment from `&=` to `&[`. The output is unchanged in this case as the left hand sides of each group have the same width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&[f_2,\phi](a)=0, &&[f_2,\psi](a)=0, &&[f_2,\phi](b)=-\beta_2, &&[f_2,\psi](b)=\beta_1.\\
&[f_1,\phi](a)=-\alpha_2, &&[f_1,\psi](a)=\alpha_1, &&[f_1,\phi](b)=0, &&[f_1,\psi](b)=0.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

To better see the difference, the two forms, but replacing `f_1` and `f_2` by variables of different widths:

[image]